# Laravel application is unable to write to files locally, throwing a permission denied using docker

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am using Docker to create a laravel application.

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine:3.6
ENV LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8" \
     LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8" \
     LANGUAGE="fr_FR.UTF-8" \
     TERM="xterm" \
     COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

EXPOSE 80

RUN  apk add --no-cache \
        shadow \
        nginx \
        git \
        curl \
        wget \
        bash \
        supervisor \
        php7 \
        php7-common \
        php7-fpm \
        php7-dom \
        php7-curl \
        php7-phar \
        php7-bcmath \
        php7-intl \
        php7-json \
        php7-iconv \
        php7-mcrypt \
        php7-mbstring \
        php7-pdo \
        php7-pdo_mysql \
        php7-zip \
        php7-bcmath \
        php7-opcache \
        php7-apcu \
        php7-imagick \
        php7-xml \
         php7-xmlwriter \
        php7-ctype \
        php7-tokenizer \
        php7-session \
        php7-simplexml \
        php7-fileinfo \
        php7-zlib \
        openssl \
        tzdata  \
        ca-certificates \
        && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime && echo "Europe/Paris" > /etc/timezone \
        && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY composer.json composer.lock /var/www/
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-autoloader --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-dev

RUN set -x ; \
    addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
    adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

COPY  . /var/www/

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data storage
RUN chmod -R 775 storage 
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/storage
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data docker

RUN mkdir -p var/cache && \
    mkdir -p var/log && \
    mkdir -p var/sessions && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data var/cache && \
    chmod -R 775 var/cache && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data var/log && \
    chmod -R 775 var/log && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data var/sessions && \
    chmod -R 775 var/sessions && \
    mv docker/prod/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/50_settings.ini && \
    composer dump-autoload && \
    php artisan cache:clear && \
    rm -rf /etc/supervisord.conf && \
    mv docker/prod/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf && \
    rm -rf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && \
    mv docker/prod/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/bootstrap/cache && \
    chmod -R 775 /var/www/bootstrap/cache && \
     chown -R www-data:www-data   storage/framework/views/ && \
      chmod -R 775    storage/framework/views/  && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data  /var/tmp/nginx/


# Cleanup 
RUN apk del git \
     && find / -type f -iname \*.apk-new -delete \
     && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/* /root/.composer

ADD docker/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
 

#entrypoint will take CMD as an argument
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

When I try to submit a form, I have the following error:

```
The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I know the problem come from files permission , I check and I have for storage :

```
drwxrwxr-x    5 www-data www-data      4096 Jul 19 12:20 storage
```

And the same for the directories and files inside.

My nginx.conf:

```
daemon off;
user www-data;
worker_processes 5;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

error_log /dev/stdout info;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;
        ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    client_body_buffer_size 256K;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        client_max_body_size 800M;
        root /var/www/public;
#custom cors ici ? 
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
#changements par oip ok ?
        location / {
            #root /var/www/public;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            #index index.php;
            #try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
            try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
 
        }
#pas besoin car par d'images ? 
        # location ~*  \.(ico|css|js|woff|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$ {
        #     root /oip/public/app;

        #     access_log        off;
        #     log_not_found     off;
        #     expires 365d;
        # }
# pas besoin car configuré sur / 
        # location /rest {
        #     index index.php;
        #     try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        # }
# non concerné
        # location /sauth {
        #     index index.php;
        #     try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        # }

        location ~ \.php(/|$) {
            internal;

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #qu'implique APP_ENV ?
            fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
            # https off ? 
            fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        }
    }
}
```

When I chmod 777 on storage, it is working but I known it is not good pratices to do this.
I was thinking my webserver was using www-data but it can't write  laravel.log
What should I be doing to resolve this?

### EDIT :

After some test , I find my application laravel is using the user nobody to write files , I really don't know why

Comment: is the server ran by `www-data`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova yes ,when I put a var_dump(get_current_user()) in my code I have www-data